# sudo password fail trying to setup monit for rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, monit

I'm following along with Ryan Bates' Railscast on Monit http://railscasts.com/episodes/375-monit?view=asciicast, the monitoring system for Rails applications. In it, he creates a capistrano recipe for monit (see below) which runs with the command `cap monit:setup`. When I run it, it fails with this message

```
command finished in 200ms
    failed: "sh -c 'sudo -p '\\''sudo password: '\\'' service monit reload'" on 192.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

It's obviously a password related error, but I can't figure out why it's happening because the earlier commands that the script runs `start stop restart syntax reload` seem to run successfully until it gets to `reload`.

Noting that the second last line in the script uses `root`, I thought it might also be a `root` issue, since I'm logged into my server with a different user name (but with sudo permissions). Therefore, I changed `root` in the second last line to my user name and ran `cap monit:setup` again but I got the same error.

```
* 2013-07-10 05:52:01 executing `monit:syntax'
  * executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: ' service monit syntax"
    servers: ["192.XXX.XXX.XXX"]
    [192.XXX.XXX.XXX] executing command
 ** [out :: 192.XXX.XXX.XXX] Control file syntax OK
    command finished in 248ms
  * 2013-07-10 05:52:02 executing `monit:reload'
  * executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: ' service monit reload"
    servers: ["192.XXX.XXX.XXX"]
    [192.XXX.XXX.XXX] executing command
 ** [out :: 192.XXX.XXX.XXX] Usage: /etc/init.d/monit {start|stop|restart|force-reload|syntax}
    command finished in 200ms
failed: "sh -c 'sudo -p '\\''sudo password: '\\'' service monit reload'" on 192.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

the Monit.rb recipe

```
namespace :monit do
  desc "Install Monit"
  task :install do
    run "#{sudo} apt-get -y install monit"
  end
  after "deploy:install", "monit:install"

  desc "Setup all Monit configuration"
  task :setup do
    monit_config "nginx"
    syntax
    reload
  end
  after "deploy:setup", "monit:setup"

  %w[start stop restart syntax reload].each do |command|
    desc "Run Monit #{command} script"
    task command do
      run "#{sudo} service monit #{command}"
    end
  end
end

def monit_config(name, destination = nil)
  destination ||= "/etc/monit/conf.d/#{name}.conf"
  template "monit/#{name}.erb", "/tmp/monit_#{name}"
  run "#{sudo} mv /tmp/monit_#{name} #{destination}"
  run "#{sudo} chown root #{destination}"
  run "#{sudo} chmod 600 #{destination}"
end
```

Comment: Did you try running this failed command by hand? I'm pretty sure there's an error/typo in it but coudn't spot it.

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel no I didn't, I'm not quite sure what command exactly to run (just `sudo service monit reload` ?) or where to run it (does it have to be a certain directory in the shell?), and, after that, would I run the whole script again?

Comment: I see a couple of escaped quotes inside of quotes in here: `sh -c 'sudo -p '\\''sudo password: '\\'' service monit reload'`. YOu are really sure it's not worth your 30 secs to test?

Comment: I ran `sudo service monit reload` in the shell and got this `Usage: /etc/init.d/monit {start|stop|restart|force-reload|syntax}` . Does that indicate anything to you? Does it mean I ran it in the wrong directory? Regarding your last comment, I'm not sure where exactly those escape quotes are coming from as I don't see them in the cap recipe.

Comment: First time bash user? `Usage` means you run command in a wrong way. It indicates in this case that there's no `reload`, but there is `restart` which shoud do what you want.

Comment: If you ever get `usage ...` as a return from command it means that you provided wrong params.

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel ok, thanks for the tip (learning bash as I'm going). You were right about the problem

Comment: Rule of thumb is - if bash command now working run it by hand!